# Unity gradle error: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, admob

After importing the [newest admob package](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v3.18.1), I can no longer build the app. I always get this "Gradle build failed" error.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe -classpath "E:\Unity\2018.2.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
C:\Users\bjell\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0.aar\0ff9f681367b6a844235e6c9eb7fcb0b\res\values\values.xml:7:5-71: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\bjell\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0.aar\0ff9f681367b6a844235e6c9eb7fcb0b\res\values\values.xml:7:5-71: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

E:\Unity\Project Trivia\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:97: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
E:\Unity\Project Trivia\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:97: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
]
stdout[
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
:Firebase:processReleaseManifest
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:checkReleaseManifest
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseManifest
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:compileReleaseAidl
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript
:Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
:Firebase:generateReleaseResources
:Firebase:packageReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseRenderscript
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseResValues
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseManifest
E:\Unity\Project Trivia\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
    activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:platformAttrExtractor
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:platformAttrExtractor
:Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:Firebase:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
:Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:javaPreCompileRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
:Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
:Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseAssets
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseShaders
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseShaders
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseAssets
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:validateSigningRelease
:Firebase:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:mergeReleaseResources
:Firebase:verifyReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:verifyReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseSources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:extractReleaseAnnotations
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:bundleRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseSources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:assembleRelease
:Firebase:processReleaseResources
:processReleaseResources FAILED
67 actionable tasks: 50 executed, 17 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I've tried a few different versions of the package, but I can't seem to find one that works with my project. I've also tried to build for different target API's, but I can't seem to find one that works. Any ideas on how to fix this error?

**Edit:** I've tried re-installing the SDK and JDK, and also tried several different versions of both, but I'm still stuck with this error. Setting the build system to internal allows me to at least finish the build, but the app completely breaks. I've also tried re-installing the firebase packages, as well as the AdMob unity package which initiates the issue. Still the same error.